# How to represent a list of tags for Weka?

Tags: weka, pentaho, kettle, arff, apriori

I want to use the Association algorithm (Apriori), but my records have arbitrary tags i.e.

```
  ...other stuff...,"tag1,tag2,tag4"
  ...other stuff...,"tag1,tag2,tag5"
  ...other stuff...,"tag1,tag3,tag5"
```

i.e. a comma-separated list of tags is stuffed at the end of each record as a quoted text field.

When this is run through the ARFF plug-in in Pentaho Kettle, the output for this column is 'Nominal', with each combination of tags as a discrete value.

The proper thing  to do is to get each tag to be treated as a boolean so it can have its own separate value independent from the other tags.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter that Weka provides called **"NominalToBinary"**.  Its purpose, somewhat obviously, is to turn nominal attributes to binary.  **You can read more about this filter [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NominalToBinary.html)**.

Some of its pertinent options are:

1. Choose the attributes to which the filter will be applied.
2. Choose whether or not the new binary attributes are treated as nominal or numeric.